# Dynkin pi-system lemma

Tags: measure-theory

I have a pretty trivial question which I am really struggling to get to grips with, and I get the feeling I am missing something simple so hopefully I'll be able to clear this issue up here.

The lemma states: If G is a $\pi$-system, then the $d$-system (dynkin-system) generated by G is the $\sigma$-field generated by G.

In the proof I have, we construct the following set:
$D_{1}$ = { B $\in$ $d(G)$ : $\forall$ C $\in$ G, B $\cap$ C $\in$ $d(G)$ }

and we show that $D_{1}$ is infact a $d$-system. I am happy with the remainder of the proof but struggling to see why the whole set $\Omega \in D_{1}$?

By definition of a dynkin-system I know that we must have $\Omega \in d(G)$ so in the set $D_{1}$ I can take element $B = \Omega \in d(G)$ but I can't deduce why the set C must contain $\Omega$ (so that the intersection of $\Omega \cap \Omega = \Omega \in d(G)$) which ultimately will show the first part that $D_{1}$ is infact a d-system.

Any help on the above would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This definitions are indeed confusing.
Notice that, by definition $G\subseteq d(G)$ because $d(G)$ is the **smallest** Dynkin system **containing** $G.$ Notice then that if $x\in G,$ then $x\in d(G).$ So, $\Omega \in d(G)$ by definition and if $C\in G$ then $C\cap \Omega =C\in d(G)$ so $\Omega \in D_1.$

Comment: Thank you so much! Super helpful and very clearly explained :)

Comment: @red_monkey1 Glad to help.